# How do I add data labels on a bar chart & add value from cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Wanting to add labels and retrieve values from cell to all the bars on the graph dynamically but the solution below is fixed on specific number of bars and rows. Needing a dynamic way to do it

I've used the macro recorder and the below function comes up. However, this only allows me to add dependently to each series given .

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
```

Similarly for the values from cells function which is called from the sheet named ABCs where starting from row 2 correspond to the 1st series on the graph.

```
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
        InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=ABCs!$2:$2", 0
    Selection.ShowRange = True
    Selection.ShowValue = False
```

Ideally, I want a code that can add labels and values from cells dynamically independent on the number of bars on the graph & rows from the ABCs sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May modify the test code to your requirement. 
After adding data labels, get  the particular series collection's range by manipulating `FormulaLocal` of the series. Then loop through each Cells in Range (or Each points in the series and set `Datalabel.Text` from an offset of your desire.

```
Sub test()
Dim Cht As Chart, Srs As Series, Pnt As Long
Dim Rng As Range, cel As Range, Xstr As String

Set Cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
Set Srs = Cht.SeriesCollection(1)
Xstr = Srs.FormulaLocal
Set Rng = Range(Split(Xstr, ",")(2))

    Pnt = 1
    For Each cell In Rng.Cells
    Srs.Points(Pnt).DataLabel.Text = cell.Offset(2, 0).Value ' Set offset according to your desired Row / Column from seriescollection range
    Pnt = Pnt + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLQQg.png)

since I tested the code in Excel 2007, may be it would be required to replace  `SeriesCollection` with `FullSeriesCollection`.May please try and feedback.